# Running Apache as a different user 5

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, php

I was work many hours for run apache different user. But I cant do this.

At first I was add new user **"test"(ID: 1100)** with new group **"test"(ID: 1200)**. Then I was change **nobody** to **test** in apache configuration file(`/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf`);

```
User test
Group test
```

After I was change user and group php files in `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/` with own folders. They have permission `755`.

Finally restart apache `service httpd restart`

When I was test my php file with http post param I got this error(`in /usr/local/apache/logs`);

```
[access_log] > "POST /db/test.php HTTP/1.1" 500 533
[error_log]  > SecurityException in Application.cpp:175: Calling user is not webserver user!
```

If I was change test to nobody in apache configuration everythings works fine. This seems to be user permission problem. How I can solve this problem?

```
Apache/2.4.25
PHP version: 5.6.30
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: You need to dig deeper into what is calling what - Application.cpp isn't apache as far as I know... so you're calling some program from apache, and that program is expecting to be called by user nobody...

Comment: I research this problem more time but I could not find any solution. I dont know what can I do now :) Maybe change to nobody :|

Comment: What are you running on top of apache ? If you were serving a simple html page it'd work...

Comment: I was use http post for database operations via php file. Maybe suphp user problem. Html pages works. I got problem when post param php file(access log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `suphp.conf`and make sure `webserver_user` is set to `test` (in your case)